# rails Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to load the user's show view, it get the error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

it specifically points to the **second line** in the `UsersController`:

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id]) ## shows the error in this line
end
```

The funny thing is, it **USED** to load, up until I changed the **routes** to this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'users/show'
  root 'users#show'
  get 'welcome/index'
  resources :users
end
```

Why am I getting this error after changing the routes?(which I changed, because my objective is to go straight to the users profile after devise log in)How can it be fixed?

Oh, and the following is my user show view in case the error is in there:

```
<h1>This is the user show view </h1>
<p>Your email is: <%= @user.email %></p>
<p>Your name is: <%= @user.name %></p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to go to `show` action after login, instead of  `@user = User.find(params[:id])`, you can do `@user = current_user`

Comment: That did it, thank you very much!

Comment: I have added it as answer. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

This does not work:

```
root 'users#show'
```

It tells rails to use your users#show page as startpage
But rails does not know which user it should show then. There is no user id given then. That is why you see in the error message `id=` without something behind the equal sign.

Comment: Noted, that makes sense, thank you.
However, an answer above had me just change the show action in the users controller to:
    @user = current_user     #(instead of:  User.find(params[:id])
That worked, but is that also acceptable, or will that cause negative effects later?

Comment: It works. but then, the show action can no longer display the page of another user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to show action after login, instead of

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

you can do:

```
 @user = current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Devise by default redirects you to the root path.

The default root path 'welcome/index' is a collection action. That is, it does not need an id to be passed in.

Now you have changed that to a member action 'users/show/:id'. So you need to pass in the id.

The simplest way is to override devise in application controller like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)      
    redirect_to root_path(current_user.id)  
end
```